# NavController destination unknown using BottomNavigation

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation-graph

I'm using BottomNavigation in the main menu class to cycle through Fragments in the main screen. The weird thing about this is my app crashes because NavController doesn't find the destination in one of four fragments. MainMenuFragment is not the same as MainMenu (activity containing the fragment and NavHostFragment). Any idea why this is happening?

NavGraph: http://prntscr.com/pcfufk

Activity (MainMenu.java) screen http://prntscr.com/pcgcnv

**In MainMenu.java:**

```
private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener listener = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.addorder:
                    args.putString("UID", UID);
                    controller.navigate(R.id.action_mainMenuFragment_to_addOrderFragment, args);
                    break;
                case R.id.addcust:
                    bundle.putString("UID", UID);
                    controller.navigate(R.id.action_mainMenuFragment_to_addCustomerFragment);
                    break;
                case R.id.barcodeScan:
                    controller.navigate(R.id.action_mainMenuFragment_to_addProductFragment);
                    break;
                case R.id.home:
                    bundle.putString("UID", UID);
                    if (controller.getCurrentDestination() != null && controller.getCurrentDestination().getId() == R.id.mainMenuFragment) {
                        controller.navigate(R.id.mainMenuFragment, bundle);
                    }
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    };
```

**onCreate in MainMenu.java:**

```
bundle.putString("UID", UID);
        controller = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.fragment_container);
        controller.navigate(R.id.mainMenuFragment, bundle);
```

**NavGraph xml**

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/navigation_mainmenu"
    app:startDestination="@id/mainMenuFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/addCustomerFragment"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.barcodereader.fragments.customer.addCustomerFragment"
        android:label="addcustomerfragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/addcustomerfragment" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mainMenuFragment"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.barcodereader.fragments.mainmenu.mainMenuFragment"
        android:label="mainmenufragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/mainmenufragment">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_mainMenuFragment_to_addProductFragment"
            app:destination="@id/addProductFragment"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/fui_slide_in_right"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/fui_slide_out_left"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/fui_slide_out_left"
            app:popUpTo="@+id/mainMenuFragment" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_mainMenuFragment_self"
            app:destination="@id/mainMenuFragment" />

        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_mainMenuFragment_to_addOrderFragment"
            app:destination="@id/addOrderFragment"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/fui_slide_in_right"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/fui_slide_out_left"
            app:popUpTo="@+id/mainMenuFragment" />
        <argument
            android:name="UID"
            app:argType="string"
            app:nullable="false" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_mainMenuFragment_to_addCustomerFragment"
            app:destination="@id/addCustomerFragment"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/fui_slide_in_right"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/fui_slide_out_left"
            app:popUpTo="@+id/navigation_mainmenu" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/addProductFragment"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.barcodereader.fragments.products.addProductFragment"
        android:label="addproductfragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/addproductfragment" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/additionalInfoFragment"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.barcodereader.fragments.orders.additionalInfoFragment"
        android:label="addinfofragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/addinfofragment">
        <argument
            android:name="UID"
            app:argType="string" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/addOrderFragment"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.barcodereader.fragments.orders.addOrderFragment"
        android:label="choosecustomerfragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/choosecustomerfragment">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_addOrderFragment_to_additionalInfoFragment"
            app:destination="@id/additionalInfoFragment"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/fui_slide_in_right"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/fui_slide_out_left"
            app:popUpTo="@+id/mainMenuFragment" />
        <argument
            android:name="UID"
            app:argType="string" />
    </fragment>
```

Comment: add your navGraph xml code

Comment: Updated the question with the xml code

Comment: Change this mainMenuFragment to action_mainMenuFragment_self

Comment: @Rajnishsuryavanshi I'm not sure you understand the problem. When I click on one of the four BottomNavigation items, app crashes, and displays   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: navigation destination action_mainMenuFragment_to_addCustomerFragment is unknown to this NavController.

Comment: So each time I press an item in the bottom navigation and then another, it is a possibility it won't detect a destination.

Comment: You don't need to define `OnNavigationItemSelectedListener` in `MainActivity`

Comment: Yeah I figured that out. Navigation works okay, but now the problem is passing arguments from Main Class to fragments in the navigation, it just doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using BottomNavigationView with NavigationUI using NavigationUI.setupWithNavigationController(controller) should solve the problem.

Links to sources:
https://medium.com/@vepetruskova/the-new-android-in-app-navigation-f7bfbe925b9
https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui